# How to update a many to many relationship in Play framework 2 and ebean?

Tags: playframework, many-to-many, playframework-2.0, updating, ebean

How do I update a many to many relationship in Play framework 2 and ebean?  I keep getting errors like this:

```
[PersistenceException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_field_event" Detail: Key (field_id, event_id)=(3, 21) already exists.]
```

I'm trying to select which fields belong to an event using a form.  I submit a form with a List of Fields.  The id property is the only property that is populated.  I then do the following:

```
Event event = Event.find(eventId);
event.fields = fieldsForm.get().fields;
event.update();
```

I've also tried loading each field from the db, adding the event to it, and then calling update() on the field.

Here are my classes:

Note: I removed Entity and Id annotations for simplicity.

```
public class Event {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "events")
        public List<Field> fields;
    }
}

public class Field {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Event> events;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but it seems to do the trick.  I just need to call `updateFields()`:

```
public static void removeField(Long eventId, Long fieldId) {
    Event event = Event.find.setId(eventId).fetch("fields").findUnique();
    event.fields.remove(Field.find.ref(String.valueOf(fieldId)));
    event.saveManyToManyAssociations("fields");
}

public static void updateFields(Long eventId, List<Field> fields) {
    Event event = find.setId(eventId).fetch("fields").findUnique();

    for(Field field : event.fields) {
        removeField(eventId, field.id);
    }
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.id != null) {
            event.fields.add(Field.find.ref(String.valueOf(field.id)));
        }
    }
    event.saveManyToManyAssociations("fields");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem. Instead of:

```
Event event = Event.find(eventId);
event.fields = fieldsForm.get().fields;
event.update();
```

I do

```
Event event = Event.find(eventId);
event.fields.clear();
event.fields.addAll(fieldsForm.get().fields);
event.update();
```

That does the trick. However I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: If there is a better solution, it's very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I put Denis' solution in a generic function:

```
public static <T> void replaceItems(Function0<List<? super T>> fn,
                                    Collection<? extends T> newItems) {
    List<? super T> oldItems = fn.apply();
    oldItems.clear();
    oldItems.addAll(newItems);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
replaceItems(event::fields, formFields.get().fields);
```

I pass a function to help ensure that you put the arguments in the right order.  This solution requires Java 8+.